# numpy polyroots implementation

Tags: python, numpy, polynomials, polynomial-math, root-finding

I'm implementing a rootfinder in pytorch so I checked the [implementation](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/08e6252fc38d3b463879afce733c889df2af1d34/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py#L1446) in numpy.

However I don't understand [this](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/08e6252fc38d3b463879afce733c889df2af1d34/numpy/polynomial/polynomial.py#L1502):

```
# rotated companion matrix reduces error
m = polycompanion(c)[::-1,::-1]
```

Why would this reduce the error? Why would this give the same roots as the original companion matrix? This may be a mathematical question but I couldn't find an explanation.

Comment: See also the PR which added this code: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/13202

Comment: I [asked about the mathematical side of this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4829995/32049) on Math Stack Exchange, and I learned that if you reverse the order of the rows, and reverse the order of the columns, the resulting matrix is [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity) to the original companion matrix. Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues. In the line below the one you are pointing out, NumPy is taking the eigenvalues of the matrix. So that is a mathematical justification for this.

Comment: @NickODell thanks! It's strange that the algorithm produces less error this way in numpy. Maybe I should measure this in pytorch (I use [linalg.eigvals](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.linalg.eigvals.html)). I also [aked about this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4829245/polynomial-root-finding-with-companion-matrix) in Math Stack Exchange, so maybe thats' a duplicate.

Comment: The reflected matrix is automatically in Hessenberg form. This means that the first step in the eigenvalue algorithm is trivial or can be left out. This may reduce the number of operations and initial mixing which could reduce the floating point error. But in general it is advisable to polish the roots of numpy with one Newton iteration. In many cases this gives a non-random improvement.